# how to connect outlook with .net framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, outlook

Well like the title says, how can I connect Outlook with asp.net or any product that uses the **.net framework**.

If possible please tell me how or provide some references as I was trying to find any references and have not found anything so far.

Comment: If you are interested in working with Exchange and not just Outlook, you can check out their web services framework: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb204119(v=exchg.140).aspx

Comment: what are you looking for? Outlook? Pst? Or to interface with exchange?

Comment: Are you planning to do this from inside an ASP.NET web application? That's a totally different issue, as you cannot use Office Automation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to control a Microsoft Outlook client instance check out the [Outlook Primary Interop Assemblies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb652780%28v=office.12%29.aspx).

Comment: good starting place...[Hello Word Outlook Add-In using C#](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dancre/archive/2004/03/21/93712.aspx)

Comment: Pay attention to John Saunders note: automating Outlook from ASP.Net/server side processing is not supported.